# Highlight R chunks in a Knitr document when working in Kile

Tags: highlighting, r, kile, knitr

When working on a knitr document in kile I can get highlights for the LaTeX parts of the document by adding the `*.Rnw` file extension in the `Modes & Filetypes` tab under `Open/save` configuration options. The question is, is there a way to get highlighting of the R parts of the document a la R-Studio?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for an editor (Kile).